Importing third-party classes as if they were local
I'm reviewing a code and I am seeing the case when third party class
# tables.py

from sqlalchemy import Enum

is imported as it was local
# db_update.py

from .tables import Enum

Is there any downside of it? Seems like a way to allow replacement of Enum definition in the future in tables.py e.g. when
sqlalchemy is replaced one day or another with another library
I've seen this approach applies for local packages to make imports shorter/clearer but never seen that for third party libraries.
# __init__.py

from .x.y.z import MyClass


So it’s importing a name from module A that A has only because it imported it from some other module B?

@DavisHerring A (tables.py) is using the name (Enum) locally as well.

It's better to import third-party libraries directly to avoid confusion and ensure clarity about their origin. This prevents any misleading assumptions about the source of the imported classes and maintains clear dependencies in the codebase.

It's up to you and what you want to achieve.
As an example, the popular FastAPI framework is based on Starlette. And while this is mentioned throughout the documentation, it's an implementation detail you do not need to be aware of. In fact, it may be confusing to users of FastAPI what Starlette even is. Therefore, FastAPI exposes many Starlette classes under its own name explicitly (e.g. most of the responses).
This can also make sense within your own codebase, to abstract the implementation details of one module away from another. Why create a tight coupling to a 3rd party dependency in several modules, when it's really only one module needing it, even if several other modules use that module?
When doing so, you of course need to be aware that you're importing the 3rd party module only to export it. You need to ensure your module keeps presenting a stable interface, and that you don't accidentally remove "unused imports". For this purpose, you can declare all your explicit "exports" using __all__ = 'Enum', ... as a sign that the import is deliberately used for export.
